# Elegant way to insert list into odbc row using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, python-2.7, pyodbc

I'm just getting into python and SQL. I'm able to connect to my db, and query from it. Now I'd like to insert rows. In particular, I have a dictionary of lists. I'd like to insert each list into the database as part of a row. Since my lists are long, I'd like to find an elegant way to do it.

The table is given by the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExampleTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [columnA] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [columnB] [int] NOT NULL,
    [columnC] [decimal](5, 4) NOT NULL,
    [columnD] [int] NOT NULL
    ...
    [columnX] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

So far I have:

```
import pyodbc
import datetime
import time

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
db_cursor = cnxn.cursor()

myDict = dict()
myDict['key1'] = ['John Doe', 5, 0.978, -1, ..., 'x'] # there are many columns here
thisDate =  datetime.date(2014, 10, 22)
myTable = ExampleTable

insertQuery  = "insert into %s value(?, ?, ?)" %myTable


for key in myDict:
    db_cursor.execute(insertQuery, key, thisDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), myDict[key])
    cnxn.commit()
```

Here I get an error:

> ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=4
>   param-type=list', 'HY105')

Is there a way to do this elegantly, without having to reference each element in the dictionary's lists?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the target table definition?

Comment: @BryanEargle I've updated the OP with the table definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it looks like you're trying to make the insert table-agnostic, at a minimum you need to:

1. Determine number of parameter placeholders `?` required for insert statement
2. Build a sequence of parameter values from individual variable (`key` and `thisDate`) and dictionary values

```
...
myDict = dict()
myDict['key1'] = ['John Doe', 5, 0.978, -1, ..., 'x'] # there are many columns here
thisDate =  datetime.date(2014, 10, 22)

# get number of columns from target table to determine number of placeholders
# for insert, change schema as needed
columns = db_cursor.columns(table=mytable, schema='dbo').fetchall()

# build DML with dynamic table name and placeholders
insertQuery  = "insert into {0} values ({1})".format(myTable, ','.join('?' * len(columns))

for key in myDict:
    # build parameter list from individual variable and dictionary values
    params = [key, thisDate] + myDict[key]
    db_cursor.execute(insertQuery, params)
    cnxn.commit()
```

Above code hasn't been tested.

Comment: Minor typo. Missing closing bracket at the end of line .`..len(columns))` should be `..len(columns)))`